# Apache ProxyPass removes Authorization header

Tags: apache, authorization, proxypass

I have an Apache server setup as a reverse proxy in front of a some backend servers. One of the backend servers requires basic authentication but somehow Apache seems to remove the Authorization header from the request.

Do I have to configure something special in order to make Apache pass on the Authorization header to the backend server?

My Apache configuration is pretty basic. I only added some proxy directives like:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /backend-server https://backend.server

SSLProxyEngine on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's not Apache that removed the Authorization header, but some other firewall component in our network.

We changed a setting in the firewall and now the ProxyPass directive above works just fine!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to set the `proxy-chain-auth` environment variable:

> If the proxy requires authentication, it will read and consume the
>   proxy authentication credentials sent by the client. With
>   proxy-chain-auth it will also forward the credentials to the next
>   proxy in the chain. This may be necessary if you have a chain of
>   proxies that share authentication information. Security Warning: Do
>   not set this unless you know you need it, as it forwards sensitive
>   information!

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

```
<Location />
    AuthType basic
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth 
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Turns out that it's not the proxy-chain-auth, but some other component in our network.