# Authorization Header missing in Xampp/Apache?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to send authorization header with PHP but Xampp/Apache do not recognize it , header is empty. I was looking here for solutions, tried many things like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

in htaccess , but it's still not sending authorization header. 
I am sending it with

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.

I have a website hosted in a third party, and suddenly my Authorization Header is no longer reaching my PHP scripts.
I just found a possible solution:

[Apache ProxyPass removes Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057978/apache-proxypass-removes-authorization-header)

Give it a try, I'll do the same thing and see if it works.