# Apache "destroying" Authorization header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authorization

After a lot of researching, and try and error, I've become desperate.

I'm working with JwtAuthentication. My client is sending the header Authorization just fine. A couple of weeks ago I wasn't having any problems, but all of a sudden, my PHP scripts (hence the JwtAuthentication middleware) cannot "see" the Authorization header and neither the "SetEnv/SetEnvIf" variables I declare in the .htaccess file.

I asked for the active modules in the server (I'm paying for a hosting), to see if the correct ones are enable, and they sent me this:

- core_module (static)
- so_module (static)
- http_module (static)
- mpm_worker_module (shared)
- cgid_module (shared)
- access_compat_module (shared)
- actions_module (shared)
- alias_module (shared)
- auth_basic_module (shared)
- authn_core_module (shared)
- authn_file_module (shared)
- authz_core_module (shared)
- authz_groupfile_module (shared)
- authz_host_module (shared)
- authz_user_module (shared)
- autoindex_module (shared)
- deflate_module (shared)
- dir_module (shared)
- expires_module (shared)
- filter_module (shared)
- headers_module (shared)
- include_module (shared)
- log_config_module (shared)
- logio_module (shared)
- mime_module (shared)
- negotiation_module (shared)
- proxy_module (shared)
- proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
- proxy_http_module (shared)
- rewrite_module (shared)
- setenvif_module (shared)
- slotmem_shm_module (shared)
- socache_dbm_module (shared)
- socache_shmcb_module (shared)
- status_module (shared)
- suexec_module (shared)
- unique_id_module (shared)
- unixd_module (shared)
- userdir_module (shared)
- ssl_module (shared)
- bwlimited_module (shared)
- security2_module (shared)
- suphp_module (shared)
- hostinglimits_module (shared)

From what I've been reading, all the necessary modules to rewrite the .htaccess file and to use Authorization header are active, even those to be able to declare environment variables with SetEnvIf (like I said, I don't know why I can't use them neither).

And the server configuration is as follow:
cPanel Version  58.0 (build 34)
Apache Version  2.4.23
PHP Version 5.4.45
MySQL Version   5.6.33
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux

I've already try:

- Adding `CGIPassAuth on` to .htaccess
- Modify the RewriteCond like this:

  `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)`
  `RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]`
- `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1`
- `WSGIPAssAuthorization On` on .htaccess files causes a 500 error (I don't know why)
- `CGIPassAuth on` on .htaccess makes no change.

And... nothing has worked. I ask the hosting guys about changes on Apache, but they told me nothing has changed.

And the environment variables... Why are they not working?

I know there's other questions about it, but unfortunately the solutions they give don't fix my problem.

Is it Apache?
Is it PHP?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057978/apache-proxypass-removes-authorization-header) they say it could be a firewall problem, but if it was that, the environment should work, doesn't it? And is not only if I want to set the Authorization header to a variable; any environment variable I set through `SetEnv` or `SetEnvIf` can't be seen in my PHP scripts.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started experiencing the same symptom after accidentally switching my MAMP PHP settings from Module to CGI.

From what I've [read](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/18/6/0/php-as-a-cgi-or-a-module), Module is preferable for a number of reasons.

[Check the equivalent setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414507/818054) on your server and change it if necessary.

Comment: Hi! I'm waiting for my hosting provider to help me with the changes. In fact, their server is running as CGI/FastCGI and my localhost is running as Apache 2.0 Handler. I hope this is the answer. Anyway, I think you just point me in the right direction, thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction. My hosting service did the changes I requested based on your answer and now everything's working fine again.

Answer (score 6):

If you using PHP-FPM and vhosts you should add this into your vhosts file

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/local.mysite/htdocs/$1
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIf Content-Type "(.*)" HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=$1
SetEnvIf Accept "(.*)" HTTP_ACCEPT=$1
```

Comment: You could explain a little bit more why this is the solution.

Comment: Apache doesn't send headers to scripts because of **security reasons**.  And PHP-FPM  cannot send any headers, so it doesn't have.

You send headers to Apache Server -> Apache Server makes proxy to PHP-FPM with headers -> PHP-FPM runs your php script with headers.

Is it clear?